# Why does EMA in TTR package throw an error if data same size? (not enough non-NA values error)

Tags: r, smoothing

In `library(TTR)` an exponential moving average with data same size as the n gives an error. But when data length is increased by 1 then it gives two answers?

(Example data below I am just throwing in a vector of test data sequence 1 to 55)

```
library(TTR)
EMA(1:55, 55)
#Error in EMA(1:55, 55) : not enough non-NA values

EMA(1:56, 55)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[36] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 28 29
```

I did not see this error message **not enough non-NA values** when looking within the EMA code block.

Why does it fail when data is same length? Should I be ensuring data is at least n+1 long?

Comment: According to the Warning section [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.23-6/topics/SMA), the function uses previous values calculated by itself, so NA's may propogate.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit. I see even with their example of 11 items to do a 10 length EMA it gives poor estimation. `x <- rnorm(100) tail( EMA(x[90:100],10), 1 )`. So I will give it more buffer